# Can I run specific number of jobs using delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

For example I have 650 jobs in delayed_job queue.

But I wanna run only 200 from them (e.g. 200 for now and 200 for tomorrow).
This connected with sendgrid email limitation of 200 emails per day.

Thank you

Comment: How did you solve this in the end?

Comment: Sendgrid is close connection after limit is over, and I just stop the script with rescue

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `work_off(200)` - http://www.rubydoc.info/github/tobi/delayed_job/Delayed/Job#work_off-class_method

or `find_available(200)` - http://www.rubydoc.info/github/tobi/delayed_job/Delayed/Job#find_available-class_method

This might also be helpful: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/handling-api-rate-limits/